# RelationShip Eloquent hasOne

Tags: laravel

I do not understand how the relationShips are working with Eloquent. Imagine an user with one role. I wrote this in my model User :

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role');
}
```

And this in my model Role :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

After that i would like to retrieve the role of the user connected , like that :

```
Auth::user()->role->role_name
```

But it throw an exception :

```
Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column roles.user_id does not exist
```

Does it not work like that?

Comment: Can you show the migration file for the roles table?

Comment: It depends on how you have the migrations done, but on the way you have the relationships, Eloquent will look in the role table for the user's id. I think it makes more sense that the user belongs to a role and that a role has many users

Comment: Thanks porloscerros. I had reversed these 2 notions 'hasOne' and 'belongsTo'. I corrected my code and it works fine now. Now I have understood. Merci

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `user_id` foreign column in the roles table, Eloquent assumes that column to exist in order to link a `User` with a `Role`

```php
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('role_name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

### Update: given a hasOne relationship

`App\User` model

```php
public function role()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role');
}
```

`App\Model\Role` model

```php
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

`DatabaseSeeder`

```php
$user = factory('App\User')->create();
$user->role()->create([
   'role_name' => 'Admin'
]);
```

`routes/web`

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return Auth::user()->role->role_name;
});
```

`Results` => **Admin**

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `belongsTo()` relationship in your User model for the role relationship :

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
}
```

Comment: @CaddyDZ nope, the OP is doing the inverse

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ are you sure? I double checked and it reads as `I wrote this in my model User :
public function role()`

Comment: @CaddyDZ he is using hasOne, not belongsTo

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ so what? it's still correct, just tested it locally to triple check and it works

Comment: And there's no inverse for one to one relationships, [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Hi all. Thanks porloscerros. I had reversed these 2 notions 'hasOne' and 'belongsTo'. I corrected my code and it works fine now. Now I have understood.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I'll update my answer with the same code OP is using but just adding the `user_id` to the migration, you can test it yourself

Comment: Laravel relationships are bi directional. On one-to-one relationships, you can define the direct relationship (HasOne) and the inverse relationship (BelongsTo). It is sometimes confusing, but I think the User does not "have one" role, but "belongs to" an role. I assumed a Role would be used by multiple Users This is how I would do it myself.

Comment: @Dom I suppose you can accept whichever answer helped you !